# Odoo CRM problem in binding attribute to a record.field value

Tags: odoo, crm, odoo-17

I have extended the CRM kanban view via a custom module to display a button on kanban box.

The issue was getting undefined value in the rendered href link instead of the field value.

My custom view code :

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_crm_lead_kanban_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_subtitle')]" position="after">                    
                            <div class="o_kanban_record_action">
                                <a name="btn_whatsapp" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary o_kanban_button_custom"
                                    t-attf-href="{{'https://wa.me/'+record.whatsapp.raw_value+'?text=Hello'}}" t-attf-target="_blank">
                                    Whatsapp
                                </a>
                            </div>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of struggle, I found out that the field's data is fetched if its field tag is inside the record tag.
Finally problem solved by adding the following tag after the `<xpath>` tag :

```
<xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_subtitle')]" position="after">
    <field name="whatsapp"  invisible="1"/>
```